# Passing a static variable by reference in a class constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, pass-by-reference

```
public class Gameplay {
   public static int count = 0;

   AClass aClass = new AClass(ref count);
}

public class AClass {
   public int count { get; set; }

   public AClass(ref int c) {
       this.count = c;
   }

   public void printCount() {
       Console.WriteLine(this.count.ToString());
   }
}
```

I have two classes like the ones above. Suppose the count variable of Gameplay increases in another class that does *Gameplay.count++*. I want AClass.count to always be equal to Gameplay.count.

Now, surely I could just use Gameplay.count inside AClass but if I have different counts to pass in different instances of AClass it's better to have the reference to the count you want to access. The above example always writes 0 even if Gameplay count has increased.

Comment: `Int32` is an alias for `int` it is not a boxed `int`, so the above comment is not true (presuming they mean Int32)

Comment: @ext0 - There is no `Integer` class in .net. Passing by ref only applies to `c` within the constructor and doesn't apply to the `count` member which is a copy of `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would you expect this code to do?

```
int c = 0;
int count = c;
c++;
```

`c` and `count` are both references, yet mutating `c` somehow does not change the value of `count`.

It's exactly the same situation in your code.

In your code, this line:

```
this.count = c;
```

does not copy the reference to `c`. It copies the value at the time of the assignment to the value-type backing field for `count`.

---

You can pass a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) to the constructor if you need `AClass` to be able to access the value of some arbitrary integer.

```
public class Gameplay {
   public static int count = 0;

   AClass aClass = new AClass( () => count );
}

public class AClass {
   public int count { get { return this.getCount(); } }
   private readonly Func<int> getCount;

   public AClass(Func<int> getCount) {
       this.getCount = getCount;
   }

   public void printCount() {
       Console.WriteLine(this.count.ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't change the count this way. If I had a count2 in Gameplay and wanted an instance of AClass to print the value of Gameplay.count and another instance to print the value of Gameplay.count2 how could I do it?

Comment: @Cress: does `AClass` need to be able to modify the value, or just read it?

Comment: Just read it and use it to make a sum, for example: n + count

Comment: @Cress: Updated the example code to use a lambda expression

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor:

```
public AClass(ref int c) {
    this.count = c;
}
```

... even though the parameter `c` is passed by reference, as soon as you assign it to `this.count`, the value gets copied.  So any changes to `c` or `Gameplay.count` will not be reflected in `this.count`.

Answer (score 0):

That's going to be challenging, because integers are value types.

You might try using a class that has a Count property, and pass that in instead.  If you have multiple objects with Count properties, you could declare an interface with a property of Count (let's call it `IHasCount`) and have `AClass` take an instance of `IHasCount` as its parameter.

Your design begins to sound like it uses the Singleton pattern, which is discouraged nowadays.  You might want to read up on that.

Comment: In addition to being a **Singleton**, it is also a case of **Feature Envy**: why does Gameplay track `count`, if `AClass` is the one which uses the value?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the count into another class

```
    public class CounterHolder
    {
        public int count = 0;
    }
    public class Gameplay
    {
        public static CounterHolder counterHolder = new CounterHolder();
        AClass aClass = new AClass(counterHolder);

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            // Something
            counterHolder.count++;
            aClass.printCount();
        }
    }

    public class AClass
    {
        private CounterHolder _counterHolder;

        public AClass(CounterHolder counterHolder)
        {
            _counterHolder = counterHolder;
        }

        public void printCount()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_counterHolder.count.ToString());
        }
    }
```